# Nunit results XML file location on jenkins master

Tags: jenkins, nunit, jenkins-plugins

Does anyone know where the Nunit results xml file stored on the Jenkins master (if any). We run tests on a slave and the xml file is replaced after every job run. But we need the xml file for some reasons from previous jobs. I know there is a console output and published results but we specifically need the xml.

Answer (score 1):

Default state is to output to the "current directory". Where is the current directory? Look at the jenkins console output. For your stage using nunit, there is a section called `Run Settings` and a subsection called `WorkDirectory`. This directory will contain the most recent xml output. This file gets overwritten each time.

You can explicitly define another location in whatever stage this gets called in. For instance `bat \path\to\nunit3-console.exe  \path\to\project.dll  --work=\a\different\path`. You will have an xml written to `\a\different\path\TestResults.xml`

Comment: Additionally, you can can add a flag `/result:` in order to name the file something else. For example `/result:myFavoriteName.xml`. Fully qualified `bat \path\to\nunit3-console.exe  \path\to\project.dll  /result:myFavoriteName.xml  --work=\a\different\path` results in `\a\different\path\myFavoriteName.xml`

Answer (score 0):

You should check out the command link docs for Nunit. They include options that expressly defining the output location.

http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=consoleCommandLine&r=2.6.3

We used the

```
/xml:C:\testresults\testResults.xml
```

option.